# Convert int to string in linq to entities on join clause

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to join two tables comparing a column of type int with a column of type varchar,  but no mather what I try I get some conversion error...

```
using (Ginkgo5Entities dataContext = new Ginkgo5Entities())
{
    var x = (
        from node in dataContext.new_users_teams
            join udata in dataContext.new_users_data
                on new {
                    x = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)node.ID),
                    y = "team" }
                equals new {
                    x = udata.value,
                    y = udata.key }
        from parent in dataContext.new_users_teams
            where node.lft >= parent.lft && node.lft <= parent.rgt && parent.ID == 6
        select new {
            team = node.team_name
            // udata = udata }
    ).ToList();
}
```

This throws

"{The specified method 'System.String StringConvert(System.Nullable`1[System.Double])' on the type 'System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression.}"

QUESTIONS:

1. Is it even possible what I'm trying? If so.. can anyone help
2. I this a bad practice?

Thank you very much!

Comment: SqlFunctions.StringConvert demands a nullable double. But you don't need it, just use the .ToString from the id, like Liang Lan suggested.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. 

{"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Comment: Are you allowing your column to accept `nullable` values?

Answer (score 2):

Try change this query to :

```
var x = (from node in dataContext.new_users_teams
                         join udata in dataContext.new_users_data   on node.ID equals udata.value.ToString() and udata.key equals "team" }
                         from parent in dataContext.new_users_teams

                         where node.lft >= parent.lft && node.lft <= parent.rgt && parent.ID == 6
```

Comment: Thank you , but it doesn't even build when I try to use  the "and"

Comment: try var x = (from node in dataContext.new_users_teams
                         join udata in dataContext.new_users_data   on node.ID equals udata.value.ToString() where udata.key == "team" )
                         from parent in dataContext.new_users_teams

Comment: Same. Im using EFv4. maybe that's the problem?

Comment: this builds, but I'm getting the same error 

{"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}